# how to get only date from a particular date format?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have  this date format `19 FEB, 2018 3:39:37 PM` from this I want only this `19 FEB, 2018`. How can I get this ??
this is the function I am using to show the data in the `jsp`

```
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    var element = getVal(row,col);
    if(col == 3){
        var d = element.split(',');

        alert(d);

    }
    if(arrValues.indexOf(element) == -1) {  
        arrValues.push(element);           
        options += "<option value='"+element+"'>"+element+"</option>";
    }
});
return options;
```

I used split method and saw but it is returning only date like 19.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [String.prototype.substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) function, unless you need fine processing.

```js
string = '19 FEB, 2018 3:39:37 PM'
console.log(string.substr(0, 12))
```

Comment: and if you have string = "1 FEB, 2018" ?

Comment: @que1326 I have mentioned it in the answer, *unless you need finer processing*. This is under the assumption that strings coming from a **db** will all be in same format.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all you have to pass that date in variable

```
var date = "19 FEB, 2018 3:39:37 PM";
```

2) Convert it in a javascript date object

```
var dateObj = new Date(date);
```

3) From here you can extract anything you want

```
console.log('dateObj', dateObj);
```

IF you want better support for date control in javascript I advise you to use [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/).

```
var date = "19 FEB, 2018 3:39:37 PM";
var date = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // check all formats
```

Comment: Parsing dates with Date constructor is usually not reliable as browser implementations differ, ISO 8601 is safe for most browsers though. Parsing if done is better be done with `moment` or `date-fns`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regexp.

```
originalDate = "19 FEB, 2018 3:39:37 PM";
extractedPart = originalDate.match(/^(\d{1,2} [A-Z]{3}, \d{4})/g);
```

This would return `19 FEB, 2018`